# Laravel on Linux: Create new project Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, linux, laravel, opensuse

I have a problem installing laraval on openSUSE. I have done it like in this documentation: https://en.opensuse.org/Laravel

But when I run the command:
`laravel new myproject`
I got these error messages:
[Terminal Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAIvQ.png)

I'm quite new to Linux and laravel (some experiences), but I don't know what to do now. The error message gives me some problems, but I don't know how to fix that. Maybe someone can help me.

I'm running:
openSUSE Leap 15.3 
php version 7.4.6 
composer version 2.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the php `fileinfo` extension is not installed.

In openSUSE, this is the command you need to type: `sudo zypper install php-fileinfo`.

It could also be `sudo apt install php-fileinfo` if you were using a Debian based distribution (might be useful for other people).

You can also specify the version by typing `sudo zypper install php7.4-fileinfo`, where you can change `7.4` to any available version (typically from `5.6 to 8.0` at the time this is written).

After `fileinfo` is installed, you might encounter a similar error, but for another extension. Look at the message, the missing extension will be mentioned and you will be able to install it by repeting what you just did with `fileinfo` (for instance, `sudo zypper install php-zip`).

Comment: Thanks, your command with sudo zypper install php-fileinfo worked for me. My Laravel project is now running :)